# asp.net mvc session for a user can they open multiple tabs? multiple browsers?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session

I am a bit confused on how ASP.NET session works with my site, when a user opens up the site in multiple browsers, and/or multiple tabs.

I see that after logging in with IE, i can open a new tab and not have to log in, and that if I log out of one tab, the other one will redirect to login after I try to do something.

I also notice that if I log in with IE, i still have to log in with FF.

My question - are session data shared between all of these sessions?

Are there any concerns I need to take into account here?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3):

Sessions are cookie-based; so they will not be shared by different browsers (eg. Firefox vs IE), but they will be shared between instances of the same browser (eg. multiple tabs/windows of IE).

Answer (score 2):

In your case, the login (authentication) information is stored in a cookie.  Therefore, if you login using IE then the cookie is only for IE and you would have to login again with a different browser or when the cookie expires.

Answer (score 1):

You have to log in with each browser so they can each create/write the login cookie.  Once they have cookie you shouldn't have to login until it expires or you log out, which should include additional tabs.